# Syntax for checking if variable contains digits only in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was reviewing some old scripts on my machines and I saw this `if` expression and I have no idea what it is doing. Can someone explain it?

```sh
if ! [[ "${count// /}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
  echo 1
else
  echo $count
fi
```

value of `count` is sometimes string and sometimes an integer.

Comment: i think that `count` is always a string

Comment: @jsotola why???

Comment: You might be better off sticking to POSIX in that case (albeit at the expense of using a pipe).  It seems more readable: `echo "${count// /}" | grep -Eq "^[0-9]+$" && echo 0 || echo 1`  even though not everybody (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/bash-regex-match-string) agrees.

Comment: @BlackCrystal A variable's value is _always_ a string. If it is a number, such as `123`, then it is a _string of digits_.  Note too that `-123` is an _integer_, but not a string of digits as it also contains a dash, and that `12.3e-23` and `0.123` are _numbers_, but not strings of digits exclusively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down to individual components

1. The syntax `"${count// /}"` is a parameter expansion syntax to replace all spaces in the content of variable with an empty string. e.g. `2 1` becomes just `21`
2. The part `=~ ^[0-9]+$` runs the `bash` regex operation match the string on the left hand side to a set of digits *only*.
3. The part `! [[..]]` negates the whole operation, which means the condition becomes true only if the content of `count` is *not* a string of digits.
4. On the positive condition of the `if` you `echo` out the numeric value of `1` and on failure of `if`, it returns the actual value of `count` without the stripping of spaces done in 1).

Comment: If it contains digits (and maybe some spaces) it's printed out with multiple adjacent spaces reduced to a single space, and leading/trailing space removed.

Comment: why couldn't it be just `if ! [[ $count =~ ^[0-9\ ]+$ ]] ...`?

Comment: @BlackCrystal It is.  Instead of removing the spaces and comparing against digits, the unmodified string is compared against digits and spaces.